# Windows Azure - NetworkInformationException (0x80004005): Access is denied - HttpWebRequest

Tags: asp.net, azure, permissions

GetResponse works fine on my local machine but when deployed to Windows Azure I receive the following exception. My ASP.NET website runs an exe I created as a new process and it is the code in the exe that encounters the exception listed below. Can anyone suggest possible permission settings I can look at to solve this problem?

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
request.UserAgent = _userAgent;
request.Timeout = 50000;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException (0x80004005): Access is denied
at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPGlobalProperties.GetFixedInfo()
at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPGlobalProperties.get_FixedInfo()
at System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemIPGlobalProperties.get_HostName()
at System.Net.NclUtilities.GuessWhetherHostIsLoopback(String host)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.get_ConnectionLimit()
at System.Net.ConnectionGroup..ctor(ServicePoint servicePoint, String connName)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.SubmitRequest(HttpWebRequest request, String connName)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(ServicePoint servicePoint)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Comment: Could you post the `full` stack trace + relevant line(s) in code when this happens?

Answer (score 2):

Need more information, but my first thought is that you are:

- Trying to bind a socket to a privileged port (port <= 1024)
- Trying to bind a socket to an IP you don't have on that machine
- The user your local website runs that code has higher permissions of some kind than the user Windows Azure (eg the IIS AppPool?) runs it as

Answer (score 2):

DirectoryService COM can not create an authentication object. 
Review 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2009/11/06/a-com-server-application-may-stop-working-on-windows-server-2008.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try to launch the process from asp.net with specific credential.. i.e. using local user credential. It might be possible that azure is blocking unauthenticated process to access internet.